# Unknown provider name 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' Parameter name error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What do I need to download to resolve this error?

edit:

I've got the following connection string on an application that requires a connection string o connect to the database

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Data Source=db;PLSQLRSet=1
```

when I try to retrieve colmns for a data table I get that error

Comment: Could you give a bit more context please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on windows? If so open the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" in win 7 or go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) and go to the "Drivers" tab, check that the name attribute of the list matches with the "Provider" in the connection string.

Ex. connection string: Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1
In the drivers list: Name=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 Version=xxx